# Order for custom field after the loop

Tags: query-posts

I have a table, where each post has a custom field with "region" and "city":

- 01  >  SP  >  São Paulo
- 02  >  RJ  >  Rio de Janeiro
- 03  >  SP  >  Campinas
- 04  >  RJ  >  Niteroi

This query is working perfect for showing all posts in "Region = SP":

```
query_posts( array(
     'post_type'     => 'hotel',
     'post_per_page' => '500',
     'meta_key'      => 'hotel-region',
     'meta_value'    => "sp")
);
```

- 01 > SP > São Paulo
- 03 > SP > Campinas

Now I need to order the query results for city A > Z. How can I change the code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regions and cities fit perfectly in the concept of taxonomy: a way to group things (i.e. posts). And not so much in the concept of meta data. I strongly recommend to use custom taxonomies for that instead of custom meta fields. You will gain in performance and you will have a better data relationship management. Additionally, [you should stop using `query_posts` and use `WP_Query` instead](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

That being said, if you still want to use meta fields, you can sort the query by meta value as as follow:

```
$args = array(
     'post_type'     => 'hotel',
     'post_per_page' => '500',
     //meta_key set for sorting only, for meta conditionals we will use meta_query parameter
     //Asumming the name of the meta field is hotel-city, replace with the correct name
     'meta_key'      => 'hotel-city',
     'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
     'order'         => 'ASC',
     'meta_query'    => array(
         array(
             'key'   => 'hotel-region',
             'value' => 'sp'
         )
     )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I've added a link where it is explained why `query_posts()` shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this but using query_posts() is strongly discouraged:

```
query_posts(
  array( 
    'post_type' => 'hotel',
    'post_per_page' => '500',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'hotel-city',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array(
                      array('key' => 'hotel-region',
                            'value' => 'sp' 
                      )
                    )
  )
);
```

As cybmeta pointed, [use  WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

Comment: Please, [don't recommend to use query_posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)